# Convert 2d-array to 2d-array of unique values per row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2d-array of shape 5x4 like this:

```py
array([[3, 3, 3, 3],
   [3, 3, 3, 3],
   [3, 3, 2, 2],
   [2, 2, 2, 2],
   [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

And I'd like to obtain another array that contains arrays of unique values, something like this:

```py
array([array([3]), array([3]), array([2, 3]), array([2]), array([2])],
      dtype=object)
```

I obtained that with the following code:

```py
np.array([np.unique(row) for row in matrix])
```

However, this is not vectorized. How could I achieve the same in a vectorized numpy operation?

Comment: You cant have a vectorized one given the ragged nature of output. You can have a more performant one tho

Comment: Also, would those be positive numbers only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` arrays must have a defined shape, so if your data has only `1` value for some rows and `2` or more for others, then that won't do. A work around is to pad the array with a known value, eg. `np.nan`.

In this case `np.unique` will sort it all out for you. If you use its `axis` argument. In this case you want unique values per row, so we use `axis=1`:

```
arr = np.array([[3, 3, 3, 3],
                [3, 3, 3, 3],
                [3, 3, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2]])

np.unique(arr, axis=1)
>>> array([[3, 3],
           [3, 3],
           [2, 3],
           [2, 2],
           [2, 2]])
```

The result is an array and has the correct unique values for each row, albeit some are duplicated, but this is the price for having an array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to minimize the compute when iterating and should help boost performance -

```
b = np.sort(a,axis=1)
o = np.ones((len(a),1), dtype=bool)
mask = np.c_[o,b[:,:-1] != b[:,1:]]
c = b[mask]
out = np.split(c, mask.sum(1).cumsum())[:-1]
```

A loop to use `slicing` could be better than `np.split`. So, with each iteration, all we do would be slicing. Hence, the last step could be replaced by something like this -

```
idx = np.r_[0,mask.sum(1).cumsum()]
out = []
for (i,j) in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:]):
    out.append(c[i:j])
```